# making a bank balance appear in javascript deposit/withdraw ability

Tags: javascript, function

I have a bank balance text field I want to constantly update depending upon deposits/withdrawals. Here is my code:

```
<label>Bank Balance:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="bankBalance" value="1000" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="deposit">Deposit</button>
<button id="withdraw">Withdraw  </button>

var balance = document.getElementById('bankBalance').value;
balance = Number(balance);

var withdraw = document.getElementById('withdraw');

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);

function depositCash () {
  var depositAmt = prompt('How much would you like to deposit?');
  depositAmt = Number(depositAmt);
  balance = depositAmt + balance;

  return balance;
}
```

No error is received. Why is this not working? I converted both my balance and depositAmt variables to numbers and added them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just  do this:

```
return balance;
```

You need to set the value back into document element, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('bankBalance').value = balance
```

Comment: I guess i'm confused. balance already = document.getElementById('bankBalance').value; so why do I have to make document.getElementById('bankBalance').value = balance?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just can't wrap my head around this

Comment: "balance = document.getElementById('bankBalance').value" only sets balance to the value in the form at the time it is executed.  If either of them changes later, they will no longer be equal.  So "balance = depositAmt + balance" overrides the value of balance set earlier by "balance = document.getElementById('bankBalance').value"